# Detecting different heat element power

Tags: microcontroller, heat, triac

I have a range of heating elements with different power ratings (i.e. different resistances). Is there a way for my microcontroller to detect what power they are so I can use the microcontroller and a Triac to modulate the power to a specific power?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Measure the power or if the voltage is fairly constant just measure the current and assume the voltage. You can use this in conjunction with a temperature sensor in a control algorithm.

Comment: Are all of the elements rated for the same maximum voltage? (Light bulbs, for example, come in different power ratings but all work on the same supply.) This will affect the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just need to measure the voltage across the element and the current through the element. Multiply these to get instantaneous power, take enough samples and you can estimate the average power. Control the triac as desired to regulate the power consumption.

If you are asking if the Arduino can determine the **power rating** of the elements, then there is no obvious way to do this based only on the information you have provided.

Comment: How can I measure the voltage and current?

Comment: That's a different question. Lots of people have done this. You should poke around the web and see if someone has already solved your problem. If not, come back here and ask a new, more specific, question.

Comment: @Divvv app note "AVR465" http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-2566-Single-Phase-Power-Energy-Meter-with-Tamper-Detection_Ap-Notes_AVR465.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these heater elements are lines powered (110V/220V) single phase heaters, you can use a current transformer to measure the current safely and you can assume that the voltage is whatever the line voltage is.

Something like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/JANSANE-SCT-013-000-Non-invasive-Split-Core-Transformer/dp/B07D8SXQ13](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D8SXQ13)

[image]

This assumes you are doing a one-off non-commercial application.  If you need to build something that meets industrial safety requirements you should find someone with experience to help with the design.

Answer (score 0):

you need several devices like :
1. a good Multimeter for reading low to mid resistance (Ohm)
2. either clamp meter for sensing current in AC or current transformer with panel meter,, they are many choices from analog to digital.
3. a good supply AC or DC.

1. first you test with multitester, check how much resistance they have. ex: 26ohm
   so if you connect to 110V it will gives you about 465W
   you can try to connect it to 220/230V outlet but remember some heater designed with specific value of voltage and W/mm2 (surface area power) so it will not to be hot enough to be melt away for their application.

or to be safe you can try to connect it with 110V outlet if you have it (try to use line with fuse fast blow 5a or MCB 6a or 10a or more if your heater element big enough)

2. reading the current with your clamp meter, if your meter reads 6a the power should be 660W for 110V outlet and 1320W for 220V outlet

you can try to use DC voltage if you are not sure how it works, with DC amperage meter. but i think the current will flow too small since the resistance stay the same.

the best way to do it to check with resistance value (with multimeter or specific ohm meter).